# UIView's frame gets overridden by Storyboard on initial load

Tags: uiview, ios7, xcode5

I need to change the width of a subview depending on, say, available disk space. So I have a selector that's called upon the view controller's viewWillLayoutSubviews as such:

```
CGRect rect = self.usageView.bounds;
rect.size.width = self.someCalculatedwidth;
[self.usageView setFrame:rect];
[self.usageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Really, I just want to change the width of the subview.  It works if the view controller is the initial controller; however, if it is transitioned from, say, a Push Segue it stopped working. What happens is I'd see my desired width rendered for moment but then it gets changed to the original width as per its blueprint on the Storyboard.

The behavior *feels* like the iOS caches the original (storyboard) view in a block during the push segue animation, and upon completion it executes the block which doesn't have my calculations above; thereby overridden the desired view.  Any idea?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: @user1459524 Yes I am. Currently there's no constraints placed on this particular subview. I did experiment and "added missing constraints" but that didn't make any difference.  I've also called my "resizing" selector in viewDidAppear, but even that attempt gets reverted. Any subsequent invocations (e.g. those due to orientation change, button tapped, etc.) of the resizing selector work; only the initial one that follows the push segue is having problem.

Comment: What happens when you leave out the call to setNeedsDisplay in the code you pasted above?

Comment: @user1459524 Leaving out setNeedsDisplay doesn't make any difference, and I do need it for subsequent calls to refresh the view.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches.

The **first approach** is to circumvent the problem, with a side benefit of cool animation.  Since I have no clue when or how many times or exactly how iOS enforces the auto-constraints, I simply delay my UIView modifications and smooth it out with animation. So I wrap view animation around the code in my selector:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    CGRect rect = self.usageView.bounds;
    rect.size.width = self.someCalculatedwidth;
    [self.usageView setFrame:rect];
    [self.usageView setNeedsDisplay];
}];
```

Then I'd call my selector in my controller's viewDidAppear:animated:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(resetUsageView) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
```

Now most would say this is a cop-out or a kludge. And that's fair.

In the **second approach** I attack the root of the problem - auto layout/constraints.  I add a Width constraint to my usageView in the storyboard, and connect its IBOutlet to my code.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *usageViewWidthConstraint;
```

Then I modify the constraint as per the calculated width in my controller's viewWillAppear:animated:

```
[self.usageViewWidthConstraint setConstant:self.someCalculatedWidth];
```

Voila! A one liner.

Now what if I want animation given I got a taste of it from the first approach?  Well, constraint changes are outside the realm of animation so basically I'd need a **combination of the first and second approaches**.  I change the UIView's frame for animation, and modify the constraint as well to "set the record straight":

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    CGRect rect = self.usageView.bounds;
    rect.size.width = self.someCalculatedwidth;
    [self.usageView setFrame:rect];

    [self.usageViewWidthConstraint setConstant:self.someCalculatedWidth]; // <<<< 

    [self.usageView setNeedsDisplay];
}];
```